# Много полей или 1 поле в формате text

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет. Часто сталкивался с проблемой записи данных в БД. Например: надо записать расписание времени, когда пользователь хочет публиковать записи. Максимум 30 записей в сутки, вида "13:30", "01:25"... Можно пойти 2 путями:

1. Сделать для этого 30 полей.
2. Сделать 1 поле с форматом text и
   записывать все через разделитель.

Какой вариант лучше?

Comment: Есть еще третий вариант и он же единственно верный - использовать отдельные записи из всего 2х полей id-пользователя, время. Ну или с 3 полями id, время начала, время окончания

Comment: О! Точно. И в пхп, которые через крон вызывается. буду просто делать поиск по времени. Так и сделаю. Спасибо.

Comment: Но, чтобы выбрать все его расписание придется обращаться аж к 30 записям. Разве не эффективнее только к 1 обратится?

Comment: Да, тут от задачи конечно зависит. 30 записей в принципе читать дальше. В таких случая принято сначала сделать нормализованную форму, потом, если заметны проблемы со скоростью БД начинают денормализовать, например хранят и 30 записей для быстрого поиска и делают в другой таблице отдельное после со строкой в качестве кеша этих 30 записей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй вариант будет больше универсальный.

Завтра скажут добавить ещё 5 полей или сделать всего 15 полей и надо будет менять базу и код, в случае если всё будет в 1 поле то вам не придется менять ничего в базе, только код на сервере, и то думаю изменений будет не много, смотря как написать.

Но это только если действительно только 2 варианта есть, лучше было бы для этого отдельную таблицу для этого дела и через внешние ключи общаться с ней.

Comment: Завтра он захочет быстро найти всех кто что то делал в 9 утра и full  scan таблицы с диким like по единственному полю гарантирован. так что - только отдельная таблица

Comment: @Mike я согласен что это было бы лучше всего, но было предложено 2 варианта не очень удачных, пришлось выбирать из двух зол

Comment: Ну мы же тут не на тесты отвечаем, где надо выбрать вариант А или Б, лучше предлагать лучшее :) Ну не пришел в голову спрашивающему такой вариант, это не повод оставлять его (вариант) на задворках. Можно например в ответе блоки переставить, вынести на первое место вариант с таблицей в НФ и потом уже как примечание дописать что то типа "в крайнем случае можно конечно и в строке ...."